# Restriction of scalars of simple algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

I'm trying to understand the following basic property of the restriction of scalars:

Given an absolutely simple algebraic groups $G$ defined over a number field $k$, are there at most finitely (up-to $k$-isomorphism) many absolutely simple algebraic groups $H$ defined over $k$ with $$Res_{k/\mathbb Q}G\cong_{\mathbb Q} Res_{k/\mathbb Q}H?$$
(i.e. their restrictions are isomorphic over $\mathbb Q$)

I understand that it follows that $G$ and $H$ are $k$-forms of each other and good understanding of the possible forms over the completions of $k$ should lead to an answer. This is because there is a theorem by Borel and Serre that establish the finiteness of forms that agree at all but finitely many completions.

Therefore my vague intuition is that the answer is yes, but I can't find a precise proof. 
Thinking about it also directed me to an even more basic question:

Given $G$ and $H$, two forms of each other (i.e., $G$ and $H$ both defined over $k$, and are isomorphic over the algebraic closure $\bar k$.) Is $G$ and $H$ isomorphic over $k_v$ for all but finitely many valuations $v$ of $k$?

I think that a positive answer to the latter should imply a positive answer to the former, but I think the latter might have a negative answer...

I'll be a happy if someone can shed some light about it and\or guide me to the relevant results in the literature. Thanks!

Comment: For the latter question, take G=SL_3 and H=SU_3. They're isomorphic over the algebraic closure, but are only isomorphic at half of the completions, hence answer is no.

Comment: Indeed. But these are outer forms? (or maybe not? I'm quite confused). Is it also not true for inner forms?

Comment: [They are indeed outer forms]

Comment: For inner forms, at least if $G$ and $H$ are reductive (I am not an expert in this area and don't know what "absolutely simple" means) then they will both be quasi-split at all but finitely many places, and quasi-split groups which are inner forms of each other are isomorphic. So this pretty much nails the "basic question" I think.

Comment: Thanks kevin. Absolutely simple means that they remain simple when you consider them over the algebraic closure (in particular they are simple). Can you explain why quasi-split groups which are inner forms of each other are isomorphic? Thanks again.


Comment: I'm not an expert :-/ but if I've remembered correctly, this is proved, or at least stated, in Corvallis. I never learnt the theory of reductive groups properly; I'm not the person to ask for proofs. My memory is that you have to get your hands dirty with these $\mu_G$ maps giving actions of Galois on the root data. Hopefully someone will come up with some more insightful comments (hopefully not of the form "Kevin is completely wrong", even though there is a chance this is true...)

Comment: Arithmetic & Galois actions on root data are irrelevant. First I give easy proof of something very general: for any field $K$, finite etale $K$-algebras $K'$ and $K''$, and ss gps $G'$ and $G''$ over $K'$ and $K''$ resp. with all fibers connd and abs. simple, every $K$-gp isom. R$_{K'/K}(G')\simeq$ R$_{K''/K}(G'')$ comes from a unique pair $(f,\alpha)$ consisting of a $K$-algebra isom $\alpha:K''\simeq K'$ and a gp isom $f:G'\simeq G''$ over Spec($\alpha$). Pf: By uniqueness and Galois descent, enough to check after base change to $K_s$. Then $K'$ and $K''$ are powers of $K$, so it's obvious!

Comment: OK, that being said, we now dispose of the original finiteness question using nothing subtle or arithmetic. Let $K'/K$ be a finite separable extension of fields and let $G'$ and $H'$ be two connected semisimple $K'$-groups that are abs. simple.  Suppose the $K$-groups R$_{K'/K}(G')$ and R$_{K'/K}(H')$ are $K$-isomorphic. Previous comment shows $H'$ is an Aut($K'/K$)-twist of $G'$ (which is clearly "best possible"), and Aut($K'/K$) is a finite group. Hence, only finitely many possibilities for $H'$, and we've nailed down exactly which ones actually occur (e.g., if Aut($K'/K) = 1$ then $H'=G'$!)

Comment: Ah, I should clarify that when I said "arithmetic and Galois actions are irrelevant", I was referring to the original questions posed, not the query in the comments (which Kevin addressed) concerning properties of inner forms of quasi-split groups over local and global fields.

Answer (score 3):

For the question in the comments, Kevin is right: every connected reductive group over k is an inner form of a unique quasi-split group, up to isomorphism. This follows from an argument using Galois cohomology and the splitting

$$ 1\to\operatorname{Int}(G)\to\operatorname{Aut}(G)\to\operatorname{Aut}(\Psi_0(G))\to 1,$$
where $\Psi_0(G)$ is the based root datum of G. More details can be found on the first article of Corvallis, and surely in some other place (maybe Borel-Tits?).

Answer (score 2):

If I may be allowed, I will use a "high powered" theorem to deduce this is the case of number fields. It is indeed true that given an absolutely simple $k$-algebraic group $G$, the number of absolutely simple $k$-algebraic groups $H$ such that the restriction of scalars $R_{k/{\mathbb Q}}G$ and $R_{k/{\mathbb Q}}H$ are ${\mathbb Q}$-isomorphic,  is finite.
The hypothesis implies that as abstract groups $G(k)$ and $H(k)$ are isomorphic, since they are both ${\mathbb Q}$-rational points of the restriction of scalars group. Now by the Margulis superrigidity theorem (it was initially proved for ($S$)-arithmetic groups, but there is a version in his book for $k$-rational points which may be thought of as irreducible lattices in the adelic groups) such an abstract isomorphism $\theta $ arises from an isomorphism $\sigma:k \rightarrow k$ of the number field $k$, and a $k$-isomorphism  $\phi: ^{\sigma }G \rightarrow H$  of $k$ algebraic groups. This means that $\theta (g)= (\phi (\sigma(g))$ for all $g\in G(k)$. $^{\sigma }G$ is the same group as $G$, twisted by the automorphism $\sigma$ on scalars.

In particular, $H$ is isomorphic to $^{\sigma }G$ for some $\sigma$. Since the number of the $\sigma$'s  is finite, it follows that the number of $H$ is finite.

Comment: Don't the comments to the original question provide a short elementary proof of the finiteness over any field using nothing beyond Galois descent (in particular, no input from number theory)?

Comment: Indeed, but I find this answer very interesting also. Thanks, Askumadula!


Comment: @Menny: OK, but doesn't Margulis' theorem (say in its adelic form) require an isotropicity hypothesis (or more)? It would be good to clarify this issue.

Comment: No, Margulis' theorem does not require isotropy hypothesis; if $G$ is isotropic over $K$, then this result is a theorem of Borel and Tits (abstract homomorphisms paper). 

The Margulis theorem, on the other hand, does not use cocompact or non-cocompact (the proof in his book).